# XPath - compound predicate + test if value does NOT start with something

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I need help with some XPath. Say I am working on XHTML. How do I select all the `a` elements whose `href` attribute is NOT empty and does not begin with, say, 'mailto:'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [starts-with()](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) function:

```
//a[@href != '' and not(starts-with(@href, 'mailto:'))]
```